# Dynamic Dependencies in nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I have a nuget package that needs to determine its dependencies based on other software already installed on the machine. For example, if an old version of a tool is installed, then it should fetch a particular matching version of a library for visual studio. If a different version is installed, then it should get a different version.

Further, I think this needs to happen during build time, not during install time.

During the build, one of the pre-build steps, I think the following would happen:

1. Is the local software installed?
   -> If no, quit with error.
2. Get the version number.
3. If version number > 3.0 install nuget package "new-API-package"
4. If version number <= 3.0 install nuget package "old-API package"

I was thinking I'd need to implement a custom MSBuild task to do this, and use the nuget API in order to accomplish this. Or somehow a plug-in that runs during the nuget update step in msbuild.

Is this the right way to go? Are there example packages out there that do this?

Comment: I'd not take this path - besides installing nuget package - you need to add proper library reference to your project (nugets are just zip files unpacked to specific dir, you must have reference to it in your proj files. Overall construction, despite doable, looks very error-prone and complicated to me. Why do you need such complex behaviour for every build ?

Comment: I've got a software tool installed on a user's machine, and the library that interfaces to it is version dependent. For about 90% of the library use cases, the version of the underlying software tool doesn't matter. So it would be very nice to be able to run the code and have it build and run on two user's machine's, one with the old version of the software tool and the other with the new one.

Comment: Isn't adding the proper nuget library references a matter of invoking the nuget package manager from inside visual studio (as opposed to the command line) using their extensibility hooks? [it should be noted I've never done that before, so I could be off base there!]

Comment: Ok, now I got the idea. Still I feel that it'll be significantly easy to do this on installation step rather than on build. Because during build - on a pre-processing step, not even near to any targets\pre-build step calls, msbuild merges all script files and generates huge msbuild scrip, calculating all properties, including referenced libraries. And after that you want to re-write this "state", based on some custom conditions... Based on my understanding of msbuil I think it's can be done, but I'd not try to do that - too complex and too little value. Install step is significantly easier imo

Comment: Ah, so in install.ps1, for example? Wouldn't that only get executed when the package was added. It wouldn't get executed when the package was checked out on the build robot?

Comment: yes, in install.ps1, and it will be executed by your visual studio host only, not by build robot and not by nuget.exe. And this behaviour is by design see https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1759 . Related to build process\robot nuget is standalone utility which can be invoked via msbuild commands, but it's same for every .exe external tool - you need to wire it up manually\use predefined tasks. nuget powershell scripts are heavily dependant on environment host ( your VS in this case).

Comment: I've noticed that the C++ CoApp stuff uses overlay packages, though it uses a plug-in to nuget to effect the behavior. It is complex, as you suggest. Also, when I had to do this by hand, I discovered another option: create msbuild files that will dynamically reference the proper libraries. It isn't perfect (intellisense takes a while to catch up, and you can't alter your PATH variable from msbuild).